# Verifying stopping times...

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Let $m$ be a natural number, $$g_m:=\sup\left\{ {n\leq m: S_n\leq 0}\right\}$$ and $$d_m:=\inf\left\{ {n\geq m: S_n \leq 0}\right\}$$ I have to check if they are are stopping times.
It's still a new topic for me, so let me use an "empirical" approach before generalizing (my primary goal is understanding).
On the first one, I fixed (it's just an example) $m=6$, for $g_6$ it may very well happen that there's no $n \leq 6$ for which $S_n \leq 0$ (hence $\left\{{g_m=n}\right\}$ may be empty), besides at time $n$, we would need informations about the future outcomes ($\leq m$) to know the realization of $g$. That is (for instance
$$\left\{ {g_6=3}\right\}=\left\{ {S_0>0,S_1>0,S_2>0, \textbf{S_3<0}, S_4>0, S_5>0, S_6>0}\right\}$$
$g_6=3$ requires $\mathcal{F_6}$.
For $d_m$, we don't need informations about the future, hence I would conclude:$$\left\{ {d_m=n}\right\}=\left\{ {S_m>0,S_{m+1}>0,...S_{n-1}>0, S_n\leq 0}\right\} \in \mathcal{F_n}$$

Am I thinking well? Anyone who could help me in writing a more (this is just intuition...) rigorous proof?

Comment: As the answer shows, the correct statements are that $d_m$ is always a stopping time and that $g_m$ may not be a stopping time (in most cases, $g_m$ is not a stopping time but one can devise special situations when it is).

Comment: Can you give me an example of such situations?

Comment: If $S_n\leqslant0$ never happens, for no $n\leqslant m$ except $n=m$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is in both cases correct. You actually already proved that $d_m$ is a stopping time:

$$\{d_m = n\} = \bigcap_{j=m}^{n-1} \{S_j>0\} \cap \{S_n \leq 0\} \in \mathcal{F}_n$$

as $\{S_j>0\} \in \mathcal{F}_n$ for all $j=m,\ldots,n-1$ (since $S_j$ is $\mathcal{F}_j$-measurable, hence $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable) and $\{S_n \leq 0\} \in \mathcal{F}_n$.

---

In order to prove that $g_m$ is not a stopping time let's consider a simple example. Let $X$ be a random variable such that $\mathbb{P}(X=1) = \mathbb{P}(X=-1) = \frac{1}{2}$ and set

$$S_1 =S_2 = 0 \quad S_3 = -1 \quad S_4=S_5 = 1 \quad S_6 = X.$$

The corresponding canonical filtration is given by

$$\mathcal{F}_0 = \ldots= \mathcal{F}_5 = \{\emptyset,\Omega\} \quad \mathcal{F}_6 = \sigma(X).$$

In particular, we see that

$$\{g_6 = 3\} = \{X=1\} \notin \mathcal{F}_3.$$

Indeed, since $\mathcal{F}_3 = \{\emptyset,\Omega\}$, $\{g_6=3\} \in \mathcal{F}_3$ would imply $$\mathbb{P}(g_6 = 3) = \mathbb{P}(X=1) \in \{0,1\}$$ and this contradicts our assumption.

Comment: very clear, thanks! I have only another curiosity: as I wrote in the OP, $\left\{{g_m=n}\right\}$ may be empty (that is, the even may not occur within $m$), hence $\sup \emptyset$ would be $-\infty$ which doesn't make any (logical) sense for a stopping time...would it be enough to conclude that $g_m$ is not (at least in general) a stopping time?

Comment: @WendyParridge Well, basically you are right. Just two remarks: First of all, if we consider the space $[0,\infty)$ of non-negative real numbers, then we might *define* $\sup \emptyset := 0$ - but again, that's really a matter of definition. And even if we set $\sup \emptyset = -\infty$, we might ask ourselves whether $$\tilde{g}_m := \max\{g_m,m\}$$ is a stopping time. And it isn't - as the example above shows. So the "real" reason why $g_m$  isn't a stopping time lies somewhere else.